# Why does GWT Designer with UiBinder mess up this simple dialog?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-designer

I'm using Eclipse 3.7, GWT 2.5, Java 1.6, and the latest GPE. I've used UiBinder quite a bit, and now we're looking into using GWT Designer for the next version of our app. I created a basic web app project and let it generate its sample code. Then did New->GWT Designer->GWT UiBinder->Dialog Box. Then I added a button to spawn the popup, and a size and title for the dialog. Here's the widget code:

```
public class TestPopup extends DialogBox {

    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
    @UiField FlowPanel flowPanel;

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, TestPopup> {
    }

    public TestPopup() {
        setWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
        setTitle("Test Popup Title");
        setPixelSize(400, 300);
    }

}
```

and the corresponding *ui.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
    <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
        <ui:style>
            .panel {
                padding: 5px;
                border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
                background-color: Menu;
            }
        </ui:style>

        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.panel}" ui:field="flowPanel" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

and this is the result. Can anyone explain how these tools can hack a simple configuration into this:

[image: GWT Designer mess]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2595). The DecoratorPanel and DecoratedPopupPanel Widgets have problems like this when you attempt to set their size specifically. Don't specify the size of the DialogBox. Instead, specify the size of the DialogBox's child Widget and the DialogBox should match it fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That fixed it. Seems odd to me that this hasn't been fixed yet.